# How to sequentially show controllers in iOS (as a queue, not a stack)?

Tags: xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Imagine an app that shows a list of questions, each question has a type associated with a particular `UIViewController` (so there are several `UIViewController` objects for each type of question that the app supports). Users cannot go back to previously answered questions. I would like to show each controller with the same effect given by the `pushViewController` method.

Here's the catch. There might be a very big number of questions presented by the app, so keeping all those `UIViewController` objects in memory is not a viable option. Because there is no option to go back to a previously answered question, the app only needs to keep track of the last two questions displayed (for animation purposes, when the current question is shown above the previous one).

Any suggestions of how I can implement this in Swift? (I am also fine with an `ObjectiveC` solution if I can later convert it into Swift).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass a UINavigationController then set the delegate of the navigation controller to itself and then when a controller is shown, remove all other controllers from stacks except the one that is showing. That way, your navigation controller will have only one view controller at any time and you will not be able to pop but only push the view controllers.

Here is a small sample,

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

  // MARK: UINavigationControllerDelegate
  func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
      self.viewControllers = [viewController]
  }
}
```

Then, push all your viewcontrollers inside this view controller. And that should do it.